# Two dimensional high oscillated numerical integral

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I have some problem with two dimensional integral. I want to calculate such integral.

```
G[x_]=(1+2/π ArcSin[x/Sqrt[x^2+4]]-4/π ArcSin[x/Sqrt[x^2+1]]-(12x)/(π(4+x^2)(1+x^2)));

Expr[η_,a_,ρ_,y_]:= BesselJ[0,ρ ](ρ/2)^(-2 I η)  Exp[-2 I η BesselK[0,ρ /a]]BesselJ[0,y]G[(y a)/ρ]

int[a_, η_] := NIntegrate[Expr[η, a, ρ, y], {ρ, 0,∞}, {y,0, ∞}]
```

But This integral high oscillated and converge very slowly.

```
int[1., 0.7]
```

> SystemException[MemoryAllocationFailure,{NIntegrate[Expr[0.7,1.,[Rho],y],{[Rho],0,[Infinity]},{y,0,[Infinity]}],Block[{Compile`$6,Compile`$7,Compile`$8,Compile`$9 .....

I tried to calculate this integral with big but finite limit of integration.
But in this case the answer depends on limit of integration, and not good satisfy known asymptotics for small and big parameter $a$. How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The integral above can be split into two integrals,

```
first[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y] G[y z], {y, 0, \[Infinity}];
second[a_, \[Eta]_] := NIntegrate[  BesselJ[0, \[Rho]] (\[Rho]/2)^(-2 I \[Eta]) Exp[-2 I \[Eta] 
  BesselK[0, \[Rho]/a]] first[a/\[Rho]], {\[Rho], 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

`first` evaluates quickly, and can be plotted

[image: first integral]

It approaches infinity at the origin and decreases (much) more rapidly than `z^-2` for large `z`.  In fact, `first` can be redefined as

```
first[z_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[BesselJ[0, y] G[y z], {y, 0, 100}];
```

with no noticeable loss of accuracy.  Likewise the argument of `second` can be plotted, in this case for the choice `{1.,.7}` made in the Question.

[image: second integral]

Although it decreases slowly at large `z`, it does go to zero, as can be seen by plotting it against `1/z`.

[image: second integral vs 1/z]

With this formulation, `second[1.,0.7]` now produces an answer without error messages, `-0.0892243+0.291903 I`, although slowly (Twelve seconds on my computer).  If `first` could be represented by an approximate analytical expression or by an `InterpolatingFunction`, the calculation would run much more rapidly.

Comment: Thanks for helpful answer. Now  all work and match with asymptotics.