# Double application of NIntegrate produces unexpected error messages

Tags: functions, numerical-integration

In the course of trying to answer [69601](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69601/two-dimensional-high-oscillated-numerical-integral/), I encountered unexpected error messages.  In highly simplified form,

```
NIntegrate[NIntegrate[z y, {y, 0, 10}], {z, 0, 10}]
```

produces repeated messages,

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand y z has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries (0  10). >>
```

before returning the correct answer, `2500`.  Thus, the error messages seem to be harmless, apart from consuming time.  Nonetheless, I would like understand their source and eliminate them by means other than `Quiet`.  The option `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}` reduces the number of messages to one, which is a step in the right direction.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that the interior integral tries to evaluate first and has a symbolic `z`. This fails and returns unevaluated before being passed to the outer integral.

The two solutions that come to mind would be to call `NIntegrate` as a double integral.

```
NIntegrate[z*y, {y,0,10},{z,0,10}]
(* 2500. *)
```

or to define the interior integral as a function that requires numeric inputs.

```
f[z_?NumericQ]:= NIntegrate[z * y, {y, 0, 10}]
NIntegrate[f[z], {z, 0, 10}]
(* 2500. *)
```

There may be some way to accomplish this with some option setting or by some non-standard evaluation that I'm not aware of but this seems cleanest.

Comment: I especially like your second solution, which preserves the structure needed to solve the actual problem.  Thanks.